# Should I always post a the whole document to a command that updates MongoDB?

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, cqrs

I have an AngularJS application that is backed by a .NET core CQRS API and MongoDB database. Whilst I know and understand most of the technologies really well, MongoDB and document databases as a whole are new to me and I'm still learning.

The data in its simplest form is a document that can have up to 3 tiers of hierarchy (top level, group level and final node). When the document is first created and inserted into the Mongo database it has no tiers/nodes at all just the high level info like name, author etc. Then afterwards in the UI the user may add any number of new groups and final nodes in those groups.

In a relational database I would simply post the necessary info to the command that would insert the new rows and the command would be called something like 'AddNewGroup'. I wouldn't have to post all the information just the key IDs needed and new information to insert.

However, this approach doesn't seem correct with a Mongo. Am I right in assuming that I should post the whole document and have a single update command that overwrites the existing document in the database? Or is there a better way?

Also should I still break my commands down to the specific kind of updates that are being done e.g. UpdateAuthorName,  AddNewGroup etc if the whole document is always being updated.

Comment: Are we talking about the Write model, right? Your Document is the Write model, the Aggregate in DDD terms, right?

Comment: Yes I believe so.

Comment: I guess you are not using Event sourcing, only pure CQRS.

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Document is the Write model, the Aggregate in the Domain driven design world. Being CQRS without Event sourcing you need to store the Document state along with the generated events. You also need to protect from concurrent writes. That being said, you have two options:

1. For each command you update only the nested-document that changed, i.e. the Document's header.

It has the advantage that is fast and the probability of concurrent modification exceptions is lower, if you have separate protection for each document section in place (i.e. a `version` attribute for each as oppose to a single `version` for the entire document).

It has the disadvantage that it couples too much the Domain model (class) with the infrastructure, as you need to put the queries inside the Document class. If you mix the Domain with the Infrastructure then you don't have a pure model anymore and you lose the ability to safely retry the command. This can be done outside the Domain class, in the infrastructure, if you "teach" the infrastructure repository to react differently based on the emitted events.

It is also an indication that you have in fact multiple write models, each model for the document's sections (header, body, footer, notes etc), as a write model is dictated by the consistency boundary. In this case they would share the same Document ID though.

2. For all commands you replace the whole document, no matter what changed inside.

It has the huge advantage that you can have a pure Domain class, with no dependency  to the infrastructure whatsoever. The infrastructure just take the whole state and replace the persisted state and append the new events, in the same transaction.

It has the disadvantage that is slower than the first solution. **This is the course if you follow the DDD approach**, after you identified the Document as an Aggregate (in DDD the Aggregate is fully loaded and fully persisted in response to executing commands).

Comment: I think option 2 is the right way for me to go but I should fire different events depending on what update has been done to the document (e.g. group added or title changed). I can have different API endpoints for this that call the same base update command. I can then log these accordingly and also send messages/updates to any other users that are concurrently updating the document. I have 2 other aggregates so keeping things as DDD as possible should keep it much more simple.

Comment: @BenThomson yes, in CQRS every command generates (most probable) different domain events that you can use whatever you want, but **after** they are persisted.

Comment: After more research, I think updating the main document fields (title, author etc) should be done using a single update call (as per option 2) but each of the "nodes" are actually sub-documents (now I think about it), which are linked to a different collection (as they are a different domain object) using an ID as well as some denormalised data. So when adding/removing these I think should be using $push and $pull. Then when those sub-documents are updated in their specific view I should use a single update command for those and post the changes to any other relevant views of the aggregates.

Comment: @BenThomson Aggregates are consistency boundaries and they protect invariants. What are your invariants? It seems to me that you're not sure, am I wrong?

Comment: I would agree that I'm not sure. I wanted to break out the sub-documents in to their own collection so as to make my overall document a more manageable size and fit with the application views. The main document maps to the overview of a "module" which includes things like the title and overview of each section. When you click in to each section a separate view will display detailed information (including foreign translations) for that section. Editing that will update the sub-document collection. This means each view can get all of it's info from a single document in a collection.

Comment: @BenThomson This is my strategy as well, for every view I make only a query to the persistence, no joins or nested queries.